# Two pointers residing at the same address but pointing at different things

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DebugPointer(p)                                         \
    {                                                           \
        __typeof__(p) p1 = p;                                   \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "address", (void*)&(p1));  \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "points to", (void*)(p1)); \
    }


// memory-safe asprintf, implemented as a macro
#define Sasprintf(write_to, ...)            \
    {                                       \
        char* tmp = (write_to);             \
        printf("==== before asprintf\n");   \
        DebugPointer(tmp);                  \
        DebugPointer(write_to);             \
        asprintf(&(write_to), __VA_ARGS__); \
        printf("==== after  asprintf\n");   \
        DebugPointer(tmp);                  \
        DebugPointer(write_to);             \
        free(tmp);                          \
    }

int main() {
    char* s = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    Sasprintf(s, "%s", "aa\n");
    Sasprintf(s, "%s%s", s, "bb\n");
    Sasprintf(s, "%s%s", s, "cc\n");
    printf("string: %s\n", s);
    free(s);
}
```

The `Sasprintf` macro is taken from the 21st century c book. I am trying to understand how it works. The results looks a bit strange:

```
==== before asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: (nil)
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: (nil)
==== after  asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: (nil)
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: 0x560969cae6e0
==== before asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: 0x560969cae6e0
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: 0x560969cae6e0
==== after  asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: 0x560969cae6e0
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: 0x560969cae700
==== before asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: 0x560969cae700
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: 0x560969cae700
==== after  asprintf
     tmp              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
     tmp            points to: 0x560969cae700
       s              address: 0x7ffe8b767cd8
       s            points to: 0x560969cae6e0
string: aa
bb
cc
```

It looks like the two pointers `tmp` and `s` are residing at the same address but pointing at different things. Why?

Comment: Each `DebugPointer(p)` invocation is a compound statement that allocates on the stack and then frees a temporary variable `p1`, so all the different `p1` instances re-use the same location. (Nit: C doesn't formally require a stack, but in practice all implementations use the stack for `auto` variables.)

Comment: this macro smells bad practice all the way. Special mention to free(tmp) which will free the memory pointed by the passed argument (in your case it's NULL so it has no effect).

Comment: @jxh No it didn't, I just checked.

Comment: @qed: Oh, I misread it then. Thanks.

Comment: @jxh. No problem. It shouldn't matter that much. My guess is that if `tmp` is fed to `asprintf`, then `write_to` should be `free`ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define DebugPointer(p)                                         \
    {                                                           \
        __typeof__(p) p1 = p;                                   \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "address", (void*)&(p1));  \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "points to", (void*)(p1)); \
    }
```

So, you are printing the address of `p1`, which is local to each invocation of `DebugPointer`, so it is allowed to be the same each time it is called.

The purpose of `p1` seems to be to avoid multiplie evaluations of the macro parameter `p`. To accomplish your print goal, you can change your macro to take the address up front.

```
#define DebugPointer(p)                                         \
    do {                                                        \
        __typeof__(&(p)) p1 = &(p);                             \
        void *p2 = *p1;                                         \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "address", (void*)p1);     \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "points to", p2);          \
    } while(0)
```

---

Here is the `Sasprintf` definition I found [online](https://github.com/b-k/21st-Century-Examples/blob/master/sasprintf.c):

```
#define Sasprintf(write_to,  ...) {           \
    char *tmp_string_for_extend = (write_to); \
    asprintf(&(write_to), __VA_ARGS__);       \
    free(tmp_string_for_extend);              \
}
```

It is using the temporary to store the original pointer that was supposed to be allocated by the previous call to `Sasprintf` (or initialized to `NULL`). The `asprintf` call may change where this is pointing. Now, the macro can call `free` on the original pointer.

To avoid multiple evaluations of the `write_to` parameter, its address can be obtained up front.

```
#define Sasprintf(write_to,  ...) do { \
    char **dest = &(write_to);         \
    free(*dest);                       \
    asprintf(dest, __VA_ARGS__);       \
} while(0)
```

Comment: The purpose of  `p1` is so that you can apply `&` operator to it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I surmised from the question that this was not what the OP intended to do.

Comment: OP lifted the code from a book, he is not sure what `p1` is all about. Essentially, it's a guard against compile errors when the macro is invoked with a pointer expression that is not a variable, e.g. `DebugPointer(tmp+1)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The [`Sasprintf`](https://github.com/b-k/21st-Century-Examples/blob/master/sasprintf.c) is what was lifted. I believe the OP wrote `DebugPointer` to try to understand the need for the temporary variable, but mimic'd the usage of the temporary for their own macro.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your printing routine:

```
#define DebugPointer(p)                                         \
    {                                                           \
        __typeof__(p) p1 = p;                                   \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "address", (void*)&(p1));  \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "points to", (void*)(p1)); \
    }
```

You're declaring a new variable called `p1` and printing the address of **that** variable.  In this case, it happens to work out that this variable has the same address each time it goes into scope.

Get rid of the extra variable to print the address of the actual variable you're interested in.

```
#define DebugPointer(p)                                        \
    {                                                          \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "address", (void*)&(p));  \
        printf("%8s %20s: %p\n", #p, "points to", (void*)(p)); \
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two pointers, `tmp` and `s`, do share the same location; however, they do so at different times.

The reason for the above is this declaration:

```
__typeof__(p) p1 = p;
```

It makes a copy of `p` into `p1`, which is a variable local to the enclosing block of code. The `DebugPointer` macro gets expanded two times, each time creating a new local variable called `p1` inside temporary scope.

Compiler notices that two variables `p1` never exist together at the same time, so it reuses the space of the first instance of `p1` to store the value of the second instance of `p1`.

**Note:** Now you are probably wondering why you need `p1` in the first place. The reason for it is that you are applying the address-of `&` operator to it. You could write `&(p)` instead, but such macro would be fragile: it would work in your example ([demo](https://ideone.com/6iiAEw)), but calling, say, `DebugPointer(tmp+1)` would cause a compile error.